Error when installing easyocr in jupyter notebook
When I try to install easyocr in jupyter notebook on windows by running this command
pip install easyocr

It gives me this error
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'TBB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I tried to uninstall tbb but all the solutions I found don't work
